# Combine three Python dictionaries together

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to combine three  Python dictionaries together.

It somewhat looks like below:

```
dict1 = {'key1' : ['value1','value2','value3'] , 'key2' : ['value1','value5','value6']}
dict2 = {'value1' : ['test1','test1','test2','test3','test4'], 'value2': ['test1','test2','test2','test5','test6']........continues}
dict3 = {'test1' : [0,1,4,5], 'test2' : '[3,1,2,0]', test3:[7,8,1,3,4].... continues}
```

I want to create a dictionary which looks like below:

```
mainDict = {'key1':[  {'value1' : { 'test1' :[0,1,4,5],'test2' : [3,1,2,0],'test3' :[7,8,1,3,4]...continues} } ]}
```

How can I combine the 3 dictionaries into one?

[I am using python 2.7 version]

Comment: Your expected output is not actually valid Python code. Have you tried anything yourself yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MorganThrapp : Thank you. I will go through the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply looping through the dictionaries and assigning child dictionaries to each of the values.

```
finaldict = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
    finaldict[key] = {}
    for key2 in dict1[key]:
        finaldict[key][key2] = {}
        for key3 in dict2[key2]:
            finaldict[key][key2][key3] = dict3[key3]
print finaldict
```

I had to remove a lot of the values and tests because there were not referenced in the other dictionaries. Since you use '...continue' I assume you have them somewhere, though it is good to provide structures that actually work in the question. If you want the missing key-references to default to something, like None, look into the defaultdict in the collections module.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer works for you please accept it as the correct answer so other users may see that it worked if they have a similar issue!